# How to iterate through series of dates to filter based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to filter the following dates to return a logical of whether a given "window" of data is tracked for at least 30 minutes in duration and no more than 3 minutes between consecutive time points WITHIN that window. Tried putting it into a for loop with a while condition but can't seem to get it to work. Fairly new to python and any help is appreciated. The condition column is what I'd like as output. Since none of the timestamp sequences are reported for at least 30 minutes and differences between consecutive time stamps are less than 3 minutes, all are false, while the last bit of timestamps are tracked for greater than 30 minutes and the difference between consecutive timestamps is less than 3 minutes.

```
      date                    condition
0     2019-04-11 11:10:00     False
1     2019-04-11 11:10:00     False
2     2019-04-11 11:11:00     False
3     2019-04-11 11:11:00     False
4     2019-04-11 11:11:00     False
5     2019-04-11 11:11:00     False
6     2019-04-11 11:11:00     False
7     2019-04-16 19:05:00     False
8     2019-04-16 19:05:00     False
9     2019-04-16 19:05:00     False
10    2019-04-16 19:05:00     False
11    2019-04-16 19:24:00     False
12    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
13    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
14    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
15    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
16    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
17    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
18    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
19    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
20    2019-04-16 19:25:00     False
21    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
22    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
23    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
24    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
25    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
26    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
27    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
28    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
29    2019-04-16 19:26:00     False
38533   2019-04-28 09:42:00    True
38534   2019-04-28 09:42:00    True
38535   2019-04-28 09:43:00    True
38536   2019-04-28 09:44:00    True
38537   2019-04-28 09:45:00    True
38538   2019-04-28 09:46:00    True
38539   2019-04-28 09:47:00    True
38540   2019-04-28 09:47:00    True
38541   2019-04-28 09:48:00    True
38542   2019-04-28 09:49:00    True
38543   2019-04-28 09:50:00    True
38544   2019-04-28 09:51:00    True
38545   2019-04-28 09:52:00    True
38546   2019-04-28 09:53:00    True
38547   2019-04-28 09:54:00    True
38548   2019-04-28 09:55:00    True
38549   2019-04-28 09:56:00    True
38550   2019-04-28 09:57:00    True
38551   2019-04-28 09:57:00    True
38552   2019-04-28 09:58:00    True
38553   2019-04-28 09:59:00    True
38554   2019-04-28 10:00:00    True
38555   2019-04-28 10:01:00    True
38556   2019-04-28 10:02:00    True
38557   2019-04-28 10:02:00    True
38558   2019-04-28 10:03:00    True
38559   2019-04-28 10:04:00    True
38560   2019-04-28 10:05:00    True
38561   2019-04-28 10:06:00    True
38562   2019-04-28 10:07:00    True
38563   2019-04-28 10:07:00    True
38564   2019-04-28 10:08:00    True
38565   2019-04-28 10:09:00    True
38566   2019-04-28 10:10:00    True
38567   2019-04-28 10:11:00    True
38568   2019-04-28 10:12:00    True
38569   2019-04-28 10:13:00    True
38570   2019-04-28 10:14:00    True
38571   2019-04-28 10:14:00    True
38572   2019-04-28 10:15:00    True
38573   2019-04-28 10:15:00    True
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What's the quantifier for the duration?

Comment: Expected output either:

1. all original dates and a new column with a logical

OR

2. removing dates that don't pass condition and returning dates that do

Comment: @harvpan I've updated the original post with output. Since none of the sequence of timestamps are reported for at least 30 mins and the difference between consecutive time stamps less than 3, the condition column is false

Comment: @Datanovice I'm unclear at what you're asking?

Comment: @EricPettengill Different between 10 and 11 is 24 mins-why False?

Comment: @harvpan yes, because index 7 to index 10 doesn't register for more than 30 minutes. also index 11 to index 29 doesn't either, so false. I've updated the data with some trues. Index 38533 to index 38573 registers for more than 30 minutes AND the difference between consecutive timestamps are less than 3 minutes

Comment: @EricPettengill, I do not understand. What do you mean by "... does not register for more than 30 minutes." Is this your expected output? What is your input then?

Comment: @harvpan my apologies, index 7 to index 10 "registers", that is the data is being tracked, however, it isn't tracked for at least 30 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generalized Pandas approach where you can specify the `step` and `window`. You can use `diff()` to determine rows where the difference between consecutive timestamps exceeds your specified `step` (in this case, 3 mins), and then use `cumcount()` to identify the separate groups, and finally use `transform()` to create your `condition` column to check that each respective group contains at least your `window` (in this case, 30 timestamps):

```
step = 3
window = 30
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df['condition'] = (df['date'].diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')<=step)
index = df[df['condition']].index
df['condition'] = df.groupby('condition').cumcount()
df[df.index.isin(index)] = np.nan
df = df.ffill()
df['condition'] = df.groupby('condition').transform('count')>=window
```

Output:

```
                  date  condition
0  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
1  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
2  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
3  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
4  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
5  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
6  2019-04-11 11:10:00      False
7  2019-04-16 19:05:00      False
8  2019-04-16 19:05:00      False
9  2019-04-16 19:05:00      False
10 2019-04-16 19:05:00      False
11 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
12 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
13 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
14 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
15 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
16 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
17 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
18 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
19 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
20 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
21 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
22 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
23 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
24 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
25 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
26 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
27 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
28 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
29 2019-04-16 19:24:00      False
30 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
31 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
32 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
33 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
34 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
35 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
36 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
37 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
38 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
39 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
40 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
41 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
42 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
43 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
44 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
45 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
46 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
47 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
48 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
49 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
50 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
51 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
52 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
53 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
54 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
55 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
56 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
57 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
58 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
59 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
60 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
61 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
62 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
63 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
64 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
65 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
66 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
67 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
68 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
69 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
70 2019-04-28 09:42:00       True
```

Comment: Genius with the step approach

Comment: @rahlf23 this is fantastic, seems to work for the most part but does fail for a particular case, that is, if the count of timesamps in that particular "time group" is more than 30 but the difference between the actual minimum time and maximum time is less than 30 minutes, that group is still labeled true. I'll update the post with this example

Answer (score 0):

You could create a time/datetime structure by the following timestamp's and then do normal arithemetic/conditional operations on those to get the desired results.

```
import time

Tstamp_str = "2019-04-11 11:10:00"

Tstamp_obj = time.strptime(Tstamp_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

What the above code does, is it creates a time structure, from the given string. Now we can further use the above time structure's attributes for the comparsion. What happened behind the scenes, is we created a structure with different variables, and provided those variables the values that were in our string. Therefore if you do:-

```
print(Tstamp_obj)
```

***Output:-***

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=11, tm_hour=11, tm_min=10, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=101, tm_isdst=-1)
```

You can further use the attributes of this structure/object for comparion.

**Example:-**

If you want to test whether the hour is greater then 6.

```
print(Tstamp_obj.tm_hour > 6)
```

***Output:-***

```
True
```

You can scale this to your whole dataframe, and then do the comparisons on several timestamps.

Comment: This is interesting, although I'm interested in looking at "windows" of the timestamp and whether that window registers a timestamp for at least 30 minutes and whether the consecutive differences are less than 3 minutes. I'll try this out tonight but appreciate any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 comes with some `datetime` functions like `fromisoformat` and `total_seconds` to make this easier.  If you read what you typed in as a big string, you can extract and make time objects out of everything like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Extract the timestamps from the big string.  Return a
# list of datetime objects.
def extract_times(times_data_string):
    times = []
    for line in times_data_string.strip().split('\n'):
        date_string = line.split('  ')[-1].strip()
        t = datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
        times.append(t)
    return times
```

If you're trying to find ranges of times where consecutive times are no more than 30 seconds apart, but the total block is at least 30 minutes (1800 seconds) in span, you could do something like this.  Though I don't know off-hand if this works, since your data doesn't have a valid example.  Roughly what I do here is 1) start with the first time, 2) keep looking at timestamps that follow until you find a consecutive pair with a gap greater than 30 seconds, 3) see if this last time is at least 30 minutes after the start time, 4) repeat the process with the second timestamp in the original data.

There are quicker ways to do this (e.g., we could begin by calculating all of the differences between consecutive times so that we don't have to keep doing the same calculations over and over, then look at subsequences where no difference is greater than 30 seconds, but the difference from start to end is at least 1800 seconds).  But hopefully this gives you an idea.

```
times = extract_times(time_info)

for i in times:
    start_time = i
    end_time = start_time
    for j in times:
        thirty_sec_test = ((j - end_time).total_seconds() <= 30.0)
        if thirty_sec_test:
            end_time = j
        else:
            break
    if (j - i).total_seconds() >= 1800:
        print("Valid block of time between these two:")
        print(start_time)
        print(end_time)
        print('---')
```

Comment: This seems promising, I'll try later and see. Also, I've updated the post with some timestamps that pass my desired conditions if that helps.